# How do I switch my Ruby version for a single project only?

Tags: ruby, version, project, rbenv

I was reading that rbenv can be used to switch the Ruby environment for a single project only.  I have Ruby 2.4 installed on my system, but I'd like to use version 2.3 for a specific project only.  I thought using "rbenv local" would heal the pain but it does not ...

```
localhost:myproject davea$ rbenv local 2.3.0
localhost:myproject davea$ bundle install
Your Ruby version is 2.4.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.3.0
localhost:myproject davea$ ruby -v
ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [x86_64-darwin16]
```

How do I use Ruby 2.3 for this project only?

Comment: can you try `rbenv local 2.3.0 && cd ~ && cd - && bundle install`.  I thought `rbenv local` just sets your .ruby-version file accordingly

Comment: @Anthony, WHen I ran that command, it revealed that ruby 2.3 wasn't even installed on my system.  Addressing that did indeed solve the problem I described in my question.

Comment: cool - I will write up a quick answer if that works for you?

Comment: @Anthony, Go for it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[rbenv local](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#rbenv-local) only sets a `.ruby-version` file in your current directory, it doesn't also load that version for you.  You'll need to set it and then `cd .. && cd -` to have the rbenv shim pick up that version.

Comment: `rbenv local VERSION` usually picks it up immediately.

Answer (score 1):

### **This is the best solution for a linux or WSL distribution**

Check first what the versions you can download

```
rbenv install -l
```

then install it with

```
rbenv install 2.6.6
```

now you have installed a version to check all version you have:

```
rbenv versions
```

then to use it you can set it locally in a specific project:

```
rbenv local 2.6.6
```

or globally

```
rbenv global 2.6.6
```

After the installation you could create a projet with `rails new` ==> automaticaly set with ruby global

If the project are alwready created, there 2 ways

- Manually modify:
  `.ruby-version` to your global version
- **or** run in folder of the projet `rbenv local 2.6.6`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a gemfile you can also add
ruby '2.3.1'
inside it to tell your system to use that ruby version.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was [@tadman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47894930/how-do-i-switch-my-ruby-version-for-a-single-project-only#comment82759871_47895560)'s solution:

```sh
rbenv local 2.7.1 # switches to ruby 2.7.1
```